# Cannot start mysql through java

Tags: java, mysql, cmd

I'm trying to start my `MySql` DB from within my `Java` application. The program finds the path via

```
public static File getPath() {
    return new File(DataAccess.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());}
```

which is later called upon by:

```
Process p = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("mysqld");
pb.directory(getPath());
p = pb.start();
```

Which yields the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqld" (in directory "C:\myProgram\bin"): CreateProcess error=2
```

Executing `C:\myProgram\bin\mysql` via `cmd` works fine however.

Any clue what the problem might be?

Comment: "mysql" or "mysqld"?  also, does the file have an ".exe" suffix?

Comment: Google would have told you that `CreateProcess error=2` is basically file not found...

Comment: it's mysqld and yes, it does

Comment: have you tried it as an admin user,.? run the cmd as admin,.

Comment: running the files through cmd works fine, just doesn't seem to work through Java even when run as administrator

Comment: That error message usually has the name of the command it can't find preceding it. Check if that command is in your path. i.e. mysqld here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `mysqld` to `mysqld.exe`, as `cmd` does it internally for us(looks for `mysqld.bat`, then  `mysqld.cmd`, `mysqld.com` and finally `mysqld.exe`). Java `ProcessBuilder` won't go into so much trouble.

Comment: Actually it seems to execute .exe files equally fine. The problem solved itself when I added the directory to the Windows PATH variable